# Typescript generic of generic type inference

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic class `Generic<T>` and another generic class having another generic class as a generic type which is `GenericWrap<U extends Generic<any>`. It has a `Generic<any>` as a member. (Please see the code below)

Now `NumberGenericWrap` extends `GenericWrap` with a generic type `<NumberGeneric>`. At this point, I want the type of `NumerGenericWrap.generic` to be `Generic<number>` so the return type of `NumberGenericWrap.getValue()` can be `number`. But it ends up with `any` type.

Does typescript support this?

```js
class Generic<T> {
    val: T;
}

class NumberGeneric extends Generic<number> {

}

class GenericWrap<U extends Generic<any>> {

    generic: U;

    getValue() {
        return this.generic.val;
    }
}

class NumberGenericWrap extends GenericWrap<NumberGeneric> {

}

let n = new NumberGenericWrap();

// expected 'typeof val' => number 
// actual 'typeof val' => any
let val = n.getValue();
```

Comment: Why aren't all of the those typed in `T`, so `GenericWrap` contains `generic: Generic<T>` and `class NumberGenericWrap extends GenericWrap<number>`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually, what you said is what my code is just doing now and it actually works well. But it leaves some ambiguity for my case. Thinking in design perspective, `number` is a first-level data, `NumberGeneric` is a second-level and finally `GenericWrap`is the third level which is the highest level. So having second-level data as a generic type for third-level data makes sense rather than first-level one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why is type checker not trying to infer val type, but it has workaround though. Just tell type checker to do the lookup to that generic type and find val type.

```js
type ValType<T extends Generic<any>> = T["val"];

class GenericWrap<U extends Generic<any>> {

    generic: U;

    getValue(): ValType<U> {
        return this.generic.val;
    }
}
```